# What is this screen in vim?

Tags: vim

When using vim, I sometimes get myself into this screen that has multiple command line rows. What is this screen for? How do I take advantage of it or get out of it?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is the command line history window. Check [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_command-line_history).

It appears when you type `q:` (you also have a search history if you type `q/`). This windows allows you to edit your command and search history. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> twice to cancel.

Comment: I found myself accidentally, frequently opening this window, and since I never use it anyway, I finally did this to prevent it: :nnoremap q <nop>

Comment: It happens to me a lot also. But I use it so I cannot do this. But it is a great tip.

Comment: The [`cedit`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cedit%27) key (defaults to Control-F) is the other way to open these history windows (after typing a normal `:`, `/`, or `?`).

Comment: @Heptite: Remapping `q` will prevent you from recording macros. Also, if you enter command line history window, you can type `i` and then work as normal (type your command and hit enter), but you have the benefit of hitting esc and then editing the command like a normal vim buffer.

Comment: @criziot: It can also be closed like a regular vim window: `:q` or `Ctrl-w q` also work.

Comment: @pydave: Good point, and I should have mentioned it. It's not a problem for me because I don't record mappings. (Yes, it's a powerful feature, but I just define a mapping instead.)